# Why wasn't OCaml List.fold_right implemented as tail-recursive?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

`List.fold_right` is not `tail-recursive` as indicated here http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html

**My question is why `List.fold_right` was not implemented as `tail-recursive`?**

I think it is not hard to do so

```
let rev l = 
  let rec revr acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | hd::tl -> revr (hd::acc) tl
  in 
  revr [] l;;

let fold_right f l b =
  let rev_l = rev l 
  in 
  let rec folder_rr acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | hd::tl -> folder_rr (f hd acc) tl
  in 
  folder_rr b rev_l;;
```

I also found in the library, a number of functions are not `tail-recursive` while they can be implemented as `tail-recursive`. **How did the maker make such decisions?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This tail-recursive implementation it possible to apply `fold_right` to larger lists, but at the cost of being slower for shorter lists as you have to traverse the list twice. The original developers judged that allowing extreme use cases for lists (if you have thousands of elements, you should plan for a more efficient data structure anyway) at the cost of both uglier code and making everyone else's performances worse was not a good trade-off.

There are a lot of different ways to have tail-recursive map, fold_right etc. You'll find them in the library that extend the standard library, the venerable Extlib, and the newer Batteries and Core. The implementation techniques go from yours, to tricks using a non-tailrec version optimistically for the first thousand or so of items, and then switching to a tailrec version, to ugly unsafe tricks to do a single traversal at the cost of cons cell mutation (which also decrease performances).

Comment: Do you have any evidence that tail recursive versions are slower? I'm not convinced... :-)

Comment: The easy way to make `fold_right` tail-recursive, as done by the original post above, is to reverse the list first, then use fold_left. This has a cost that is easy to measure on benchmarks. More sophisticated techniques are available, such as using a counter alongside the usual traversal, and only `rev`-ing the rest of the list for fold-left when the counter passes a tresholf; this allows to have a very small overhead for small lists. We've implemented this [in Batteries](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batList.ml#L380) and the performance is okay.

Answer (score 11):

This question has been asked before, probably many times. You can read some previous answers here:

[Why does the OCaml std lib have so many non-tail-recursive functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012585)

My quick answer is that the non-tail-recursive implementation is often a lot faster for smallish cases. The implementors obviously thought this was a good tradeoff.